# Including another set of results into many-to-many relationship

Tags: php, eloquent

Let's say I have three tables:

1. Article: id, ...
2. Advert: id, display_on_every_subsite, ...
3. Article_Advert: advert_id, article_id

I have a simply Eloquent's relationship: belongsToMany between Article and Advert - Article_Advert is the pivot table.

The problem is that I need to fetch all Adverts for specified Article(s) AND all Adverts with display_on_every_subsite = 1.

I'm trying to achieve this using unions, this is what I've at this moment:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Advert', 'Article_Advert', 'article_id', 'advert_id')->union(Advert::allSubpages()->selectRaw('`advert`.*, `advert`.`id` as `pivot_advert_id`, null as `pivot_article_id`')->getQuery());
```

The problem is that when pivot_article_id is null, Eloquent does not attach fetched rows to any related model.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost like that, just change the following:

```
// I assume you have this inside Article Model

$articleId = $this->id;

$this->belongsToMany('Advert', 'Article_Advert', 'article_id', 'advert_id')
    ->union(Advert::allSubpages()
        ->selectRaw("`advert`.*, `advert`.`id` as `pivot_advert_id`, '$articleId' as `pivot_article_id`")
        ->where('display_on_every_subsite','=','1')
        ->getQuery());
```

Comment: Thank you, but this works for single article only, not for eager loading.